# IOCP and ReadFileEx usage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, iocp

i'm playing with IOCP. I'm trying to write simple application that async reads data from the file in the main thread. However i'm getting error(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) in ReadFileEx function, but seems i'm doing it ok. What am i doing wrong? Here is my sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

VOID CALLBACK ReadCb(DWORD dwErrorCode,DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"i was here\n");
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE main_io,file_i;
    HANDLE file_handle;
    DWORD bytes_recvd;
    ULONG_PTR data = 0;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    LPOVERLAPPED poverlapped = &overlapped;
    uint8_t read_data[1024];
    DWORD err;

    main_io = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,NULL,0,0);
    assert(main_io != NULL);

    file_handle = CreateFile(L"test.txt",GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    assert(file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    file_i = CreateIoCompletionPort(file_handle,main_io,data,0);
    assert(file_i != NULL);

    memset(&overlapped,0,sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    err = ReadFileEx(file_handle,(LPVOID)read_data,1024,&overlapped,ReadCb);
    fprintf(stderr,"err %d\n",GetLastError());
    assert(err != 0);

    assert(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(file_i,&bytes_recvd,&data,&poverlapped,INFINITE));

    CloseHandle(main_io);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use OVERLAPPED overlapped = {}; instead of memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin says, first fix your error handling

```
const BOOL result = ReadFileEx(...);

const DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

if (lastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "err %d\n", lastError);
}
```

Note that Martin is incorrect about his assumption that you shouldn't call `GetLastError()` for success returns from `ReadFileEx()`, though this is a bit of a special case... From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When using ReadFileEx you should check GetLastError even when the
>   function returns "success" to check for conditions that are
>   "successes" but have some outcome you might want to know about. For
>   example, a buffer overflow when calling ReadFileEx will return TRUE,
>   but GetLastError will report the overflow with ERROR_MORE_DATA. If the
>   function call is successful and there are no warning conditions,
>   GetLastError will return ERROR_SUCCESS.

But that doesn't solve your problem, it just makes your example code more correct...

The problem is that `ReadFileEx()` does asynchronous file reading using a completion routine and you're trying to do asynchronous file reading using an I/O Completion Port. For that you should use `ReadFile()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754068/win32-overlapped-i-o-completion-routines-or-waitformultipleobjects) for why I feel that IOCP is the better route to take and why completion routines are a bit nasty...

So, simply change your `ReadFileEx()` call to a `ReadFile()` call and your problem will go away and the code will post a completion to the IOCP when the read completes...

```
ReadFile(file_handle,(LPVOID)read_data,1024,&overlapped);
```

and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Found it myself yesterday, but i wasn't able to answer my question due to i'm a new user on this site!

Answer (score 1):

'If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero' - don't call GetLastError() for a non-zero return!  Move the GetLastError line after the assert check so that, if an assertion violation exception occurs, the GetLastError is not reached.