# I/O Completion Port for small-scale, single-threaded applications?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, asyncsocket, io-completion-ports

Let me prefix this by saying that I've never used I/O Completion Ports, though I've heard of them for years now. My background is primarily with `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, and `WSAEventSelect` coupled with `WaitForMulitpleObjects`. Please correct me if I have a fundamental misunderstanding of I/O Completion Ports in the following text.

As part of a project at work, I'm tasked with developing a plugin (DLL) to a simulation which allows a client to connect to the plugin and send/receive data to/from the simulation over TCP. The plugin acts as a server. The simulation simulates communication channels of a different (not Ethernet) interface, and it makes sense to have one socket per channel in this particular application. I do not know how many clients there will be, or how many channels (sockets) will be opened by each client. However, I do know that it is entirely possible that there will be more than 64, and that it will not be an extraordinary large number, likely under a thousand at most.

An important aspect of the simulation is that **the plugin is only allowed to do work when its `test_cycle` function is called**. During each test cycle, I need to:

1. Accept any new connections from clients
2. Receive data from the sockets and forward it to the simulation
3. Receive data from the simulation and forward it to the client

Since there may be more than 64 sockets, I can't (easily) use `WSAEventSelect` and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` to check if a socket can be read from, or if the client has gracefully terminated the connection.

So I've thought of two other ways I might be able to do this.

1. Have each socket be non-blocking. Each time `test_cycle` is called, loop through all the sockets, trying to receive up to a maximum amount of data per socket.
2. Use an I/O Completion Port and issue an asynchronous receive from the sockets. In `test_cycle`, repeatedly call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` with the `dwMilliseconds` parameter set to `0`, until a timeout is indicated (`WAIT_TIMEOUT`?). If a receive occurs, defer the next receive call until the end of the test cycle, so that a client spamming the server with messages will not cause us to loop indefinitely in `test_cycle` (hopefully).

The interface to the simulation is not thread-safe, and there is very little processing work to do for forwarding the data to the simulation, so I don't think there would be any benefit to having worker threads for the I/O Completion Port, which would just do a lock and call the simulation API. However, not having to poll each socket might result in better performance.

So for this scale of application, less than about 1000 sockets maximum, and typically less than 100, is there any real benefit to the added complexity of using I/O Completion Ports?

Comment: When you wan't speed and throughput take ICOP. A good description is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754068/win32-overlapped-i-o-completion-routines-or-waitformultipleobjects/755135#755135

Comment: I've decided that for the first version of this plugin that it will be quicker to implement just polling the sockets once per `test_cycle` iteration. The code can then be profiled against real-world scenarios and re-written to use IOCP if necessary. I'd rather get a working first version implemented than force people to wait longer for an IOCP version which may not even be (much) faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:
1) Build a listener thread. For each connection sends a copy of the socket to a thread pool;
2) Build a pool of threads to process requests;

I use pipe for transfers between threads without using I/O Completion Ports and the performance is exceptional.

Put the control limits, to ensure that resources are not depleted.